# Which series has the protagonist expanding the metal in a bullet to jam guns?

Tags: story-identification

I'm not sure if this was a movie, book, or TV show. The basic scene was a standoff where the protagonist (or possibly their mentor) vibrates the metal in the chambered bullets to jam the enemy's guns and make a quick escape. All of the details are hazy except for the bullets being ever so slightly expanded to jam the guns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Doctor Who: The Sontaran Strategem](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sontaran_Stratagem), the Sontarans use a "cordolane signal" to cause the bullets to jam in the guns of their enemies.

> The figure reveals that the room is contained within a cordolane
>   signal that excites the copper surface of the bullet and causes
>   expansion in the barrel, rendering their guns useless, as well as
>   blocking their radio signals (during which time Gray tries using his
>   pistol but finds that is also useless).

Comment: Bingo. This has got to be it, I was wavering about whether I should mention the keyword "copper" or whether it was a figment of my imagination.

Comment: The copper is actually key.  Despite what the Doctor occasionally thinks, UNIT soldiers aren't actually stupid, and once he explains to them how the cordolane signal works...